# Cómo contar registros de periodos diferentes en la misma tabla?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy trabajando en Mysql, tengo una tabla "orders" que tiene la fecha de creación de la orden en la columna "created_at"
la misma tabla tiene una columna llamada "user_id" que nos dice qué usuario compró cada orden.
Lo que necesito obtener es una tabla donde pueda ver:

Cuenta de usuarios con 1, 2 o 3 compras y esto esté dividido entre los meses del año.

Es decir, si un id ha comprado 1 vez en enero, 1 en febrero y 1 en marzo
yo debería poder ver

en enero este usuario se contaría en "1 compra"
en febrero se contaría ya en "2 compras"
y en marzo se contaría en "3 compras"

naturalmente la tabla tiene las transacciones de enero a junio, y necesito hacer esto para cada mes.

lo más que logré es crear una tabla para cada mes, pero si por ejemplo, quiero llevar esto a una vista diaria, se complica, en tanto que no voy a crear una tabla por día

```
    select 
month(oo.created),
count(oo.id)
from order_order oo
where year(Created)=2020 and month(created)<2
group by oo.user_email
```

Las demás tablas son iguales, en la tabla para febrero sería así

```
select 
month(oo.created),
count(oo.id)
from order_order oo
where year(Created)=2020 and month(created)<3
group by oo.user_email
```

pero aún con esta idea, no logro concretar la tabla final que debería verse así

```
>             ene               feb            mar
1 compra     3 users           2 users        1 user    
2 Compras    5                 3              4
3 compras    6                 3              3
.
.
.
<
```

Comment: Esta complicado le estuve dando unas vueltas pero no logre sacarlo, el tema es que se puede con un group by por mes, ahí se puede identificar el user y su cantidad de compras, pero si ademas hay que sumar y las cantidad de compras del mes y mostrar la cantidad de compras del mes siguiente sumadas con lo que ya va, se pierde la lógica de la consulta, la unica manera en que creo que puedes hacerlo es a nivel de programación, pasando parámetros por el mes que quieres o consultar directamente los 12 meses anteriores y al resultado por mes irlo sumando, pero por SQL me parce que no da.

Comment: Gracias por darle una vuelta, he estado en ello también, y llegué a la conclusión de que es probable, que sólo con un proceso externo pueda obtenerlo, es decir, crear otra tabla que vaya creando los resultados por cada mes cerrado.

Comment: Claro una consolidación con datos fijos, ahí no tendrías problemas,  lo único dinámico sería el mes en curso y para eso una consulta con un group by no tendrías problemas, que te vaya bien con eso.